# Why does php 'use' fail when I put example code into a function?

Tags: php

Having started from some example code, I don't understand why these scenarios don't all work.

Script of example code called script.php the file successfully works when run from command line

```
<?php
//Script in standalone file: script.php

//...define some stuff
require REQUIRED_FILE;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
//now do some stuff
?>
```

When I inline the contents of the script into my large program it fails on the 'use' part.

```
<?php
//class-of-bigger-program.php

//function called from some other part of program
function foo(){
    //paste the contents of the same script above
    //...define some stuff
    require REQUIRED_FILE;
    use Aws\Ses\SesClient;//CRASH HERE
    // now do some stuff
}
?>
```

However when including the script in the same place of that larger program it works fine.

```
<?php
//function called from some other part of program
function foo(){
    //paste the contents of the same script above
    include 'script.php';
}
?>
```

Why is this the case? Am i just miss using the 'use' command? 
I have found the differences between 'use' and 'include' and namespaces hard to understand.

Comment: Why do you add the use in the function? If your `class-of-bigger-program.php` is really a class, then you should

`require REQUIRED_FILE; use Aws\Ses\SesClient; class YourClass {...}`

which error do you get?

Comment: White screen of death even with errors on
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

Am i correct in saying that i should not be calling require in the middle of a function? Only at the top of a class?

Comment: Yes Fred-ii- it would have quotes there - have edited post to display that.

Comment: you should try to find the logs of the blank page, probably an error 500. Then we will have more clues to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you add the use in the function? If your `class-of-bigger-program.php` is really a class, then you should do:

```
require REQUIRED_FILE; 
use Aws\Ses\SesClient; 

class YourClass {...}
```

Comment: I suppose this is a novice Php error. Didn't know you couldn't/shouldn't use 'use' inside a function but should at the top of a class.

Comment: So you will go to sleep with more knowledge than this morning ;) that's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

[The PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) will explain this quite nicely for you. Knowing *why* you can't do something is often far more helpful that just knowing you can't.

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

In other words, it imports the other code before it runs the program, so it has to be at the outermost level of the program.